# Eliminar caracteres de espacios en parámetros pasados en una url en Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, djangorestframework

Estoy pasando desde mi frontend una URL con los parámetros que deseo eliminar desde mi servidor:

```
/api/elimina-objeto/Grado Acádemico/fecha_senescyt
```

Cabe decir que estoy usando Angular, y tengo un servicio donde tengo esta función donde tengo una petición `GET` que hago a servidor de mi aplicación:

```
eliminaObjetoNoSimilarConfiguracion(bloque, atributo) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'elimina-objeto/' +  bloque + "/" + atributo)
}
```

Después de `elimina-objeto/` viene `Grado Acádemico` pero al pasar con espacios me sale esos caracteres como porcentajes y números:

```
/api/elimina-objeto/Grado%20Ac%C3%A1demico/fecha_senescyt
```

No sé si existe alguna forma de eliminar los espacios en blanco de la url o que al menos me acepte la tilde. En Django Rest Framework, en `views.py` tengo esto:

```
def eliminaObjetoConfiguracion(request, bloque, atributo):
    model_dict = models.ConfiguracionCv.objects.filter(bloque = bloque).filter(atributo=atributo)
    print("ELIMINADO", model_dict)
    

    model_dict.delete()


    return redirect('/api')
```

Donde tomo los parámetros bloque como Grado Acádemico y atributo como fecha_senescyt. Pero al pasar "mal" la URL ya no me funciona.

En `urls.py` tengo esto:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('elimina-objeto/<slug:bloque>/<slug:atributo>', views.eliminaObjetoConfiguracion)
]
```

Al hacer la petición desde mi servicio de Angular el servidor me devuelve este error:

```
"GET /api/elimina-objeto/Capacitaci%C3%B3n/id_docente HTTP/1.1" 404 13951
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para eliminar los espacios o en otro caso la tilde o que me acepte las URL con espacios?

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tienes que hacer un url decode de los parámetros que recibes:

```
import urllib.parse


def eliminaObjetoConfiguracion(request, bloque, atributo):
    bloque_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(bloque)
    atributo_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(atributo)
    model_dict = models.ConfiguracionCv.objects.filter(bloque=bloque_decoded).filter(atributo=atributo_decoded)
    print("ELIMINADO", model_dict)
    

    model_dict.delete()


    return redirect('/api')
```

---

Para evitar los errores que estás teniendo ahora, efectivamente es buena idea trabajar con slugs. Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a la documentación para entender cómo autogenerarlos en los modelos:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

---

### Actualización

Si lo que quieres es simplemente poder pasar espacios y cualquier otro caracter en la url no puedes utilizar `slug` en la definición de la URL. Sustitúyelo por strings:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('elimina-objeto/<str:bloque>/<str:atributo>', views.eliminaObjetoConfiguracion)
]
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intente lo que me dices, pero me devuelve esto como error : `GET /api/elimina-objeto/Capacitaci%C3%B3n/id_docente HTTP/1.1" 404 13951`  En este caso estaba usando una tilde `Capacitación`

Comment: La respuesta que te he propuesto no debería generar un nuevo error http y el que estás comentando es diferente al que planteabas originalmente en tu pregunta. Tienes definido tanto bloque como atributo como slugs y ninguno de los que estás pasando es uno. Por favor intenta mantener el foco de la conversación en el problema original

Comment: @pusux he añadido más información en mi respuesta, espero que sirva para que entiendas cual es el problema.